# Stored Procedure - Knowing the next ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am creating a stored procedure to create a new customer so for instance,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Customer_Create
@customer_arg
@type_arg
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Customer (Customer_id, Type_id)
VALUES (@Customer_arg,@type_arg)
End;
```

If I have several foreign keys in my statement and they are all ID's is there a way for me to pull the NEXT ID number automatically without having to know what it would be off the top of my head when I run the execute statement?  I would like to just have it pull the fact that the ID will be 2 because the previous record was 1

```
EXECUTE Customer_Create 16,2
```

Is it something wnith `output`?  If so how does this work code wise

Comment: Are you using [IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) on your id's?  If not, there's your problem.  You should allow the database to generate new values.  As the answers explain, `Scope_Identity()` can return a newly assigned identity value in simple cases like this, but oyu ought to learn about the `OUTPUT` clause as it is much more useful.  It is worth noting that assigned values might not be dense.  For example, if a few rows are inserted during a transaction and the transaction is then rolled back the id values will not be reused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that what you want to do is *return* the new id after the record is inserted.  For that:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Customer_Create (
    @customer_arg,
    @type_arg,
    @NewCustomerId int output
) AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Customer(Customer_id, Type_id)
        VALUES (@Customer_arg, @type_arg);

    @NewCustomerId = scope_identity();
End;
```

There are several other choices for getting the identity, which are explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx).

Comment: `scope_identity()` can - in rare circumstances - return the wrong value. You should only use the OUTPUT clause to get the last IDENTITY value. (See my answer for a link to more details.)

Answer (score 1):

To get to the last inserted IDENTITY value you should use the `OUTPUT` clause like this:

```
DECLARE @IdentValues TABLE(v INT);

INSERT INTO dbo.IdentityTest 
OUTPUT INSERTED.id INTO @IdentValues(v)
DEFAULT VALUES;

SELECT v AS IdentityValues FROM @IdentValues;
```

There are several other mechanisms like `@@IDENTITY` but they all have significant problems. See my [Identity Crisis](http://sqlity.net/en/351/identity-crisis/) article for details.

Comment: I am new to this stuff...I still don't really understand what your saying...if I want to `output` I do `OUTPUT INSERTED.Type_ID`? How does it call back to those table to retrieve whatever the last value was in and add move up to the next value?

Comment: You got a sec for a live chat?

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can also experiment with @IDENTITY like this

```
DECLARE @NextID int
--insert statement goes here
SET @NextID = @@Identity`
```

Here are couple good resources for getting familiar with this

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/03/26/sql-server-identity-fields-review-sql-queries-2012-joes-2-pros-volume-2-the-sql-query-techniques-tutorial-for-sql-server-2012/

Comment: `@@Identity` kills kittens.  `Scope_Identity()` and `OUTPUT` are much more likely to return the value(s) you need, regardless of triggers.